# javafx project built with Intellij, including jpackage does not launch

Tags: javafx, package

Having upgraded a legacy javafx project with gradle & Temurin 17, using jpackage, the program runs perfectly within Intellij. The './gradlew jpackage -scan' indicates "0 Failures" ([Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/s/y2ouuvmmk7u6i)). The '.deb file' (Linux) installs without complaints, and the installation appears correct. Yet, the installed application will not launch. How can I find the cause?

Comment: If you launch it from the terminal (command line), you should be able to see the stack trace for any uncaught exceptions.

Comment: The application package is not a simple '.class'-file, but a complex directory tree with its own launcher. But I did try your solution by exporting the class three from Intellij, navigating into the directory of the main class, and trying "java main". Didn't work! Error message: Error: Could not find or load main class Main.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main.class, even though the Main.class was clearly in that directory.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. Launch the actual application you installed from the `.deb` file from the command line.